# How to call multiple functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have 4 functions that are basically the same, but with a different value..

```
function choose(value){
            document.getElementById('templatefield').text=value;
            if(value!=='alliance_update'){
                document.getElementById('textentrydiv').style.display='none';
                document.getElementById('textentrydiv').style.visibility='hidden';
            }
            document.forms[0].setAttribute('action','send_email.php?template='+value);
        }
```

if i write the functions down in a script.. it reads the last function.. and none of the others work..

i have tried an if else that didn't work..
can i pass the value to an array??

```
var templatesjs= new Array( "custom", "update", "client", "realtor" );
```

if i can do that.. how do i pass it into the value
    if(value!=='GOES HERE')

is this even possible.. and if not.. how do i make it possible??

Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here.  Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Are you trying to do a key-value selection of a function based upon the passed in key?

Comment: Shouldn't `document.getElementById('templatefield').text` actually be `document.getElementById('templatefield').textContent`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - or innerText

Comment: We need to see the corresponding HTML in order to correctly help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question.. was

```
if(value!=='alliance_update' && value!=='custom' && value!=='realtorNewsletter' && value!=='clientNewsletter') ....rest of function
```

basically how to combine all those function objects that are doing the same thing in one.. not sure if they are function objects, or key values... or values. :-/